# RxJS: How to do some clean-up before reactive search in angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive

Here is my scenario

I want to reactive search
if the value `length > 2` do `api` search
else clear data.

But I don't know to **clear** data

```
userList: Observable<User[]>;
```

The userList should be empty when length <= 2

The other question is why `Rxjs` do operator not work in angular 2?

```
this.userList = this.userNameCtrl.valueChanges.do(d => console.log(d));
```

Here is my code:

```
this.userList = this.userNameCtrl.valueChanges
            .filter(x => x.length > 2)
            .debounceTime(400)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .switchMap(value => this._userService.searchUsers(value));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "clear the data"? Which data? And what do you mean when you say the `do` operator does not work? You've not even shown how you've attempted to use it.

Comment: `do` works fine with Angular2

Comment: userList: Observable<User[]>;
The userList should be empty when length <= 2.

Comment: Remove the filter(), and in your switchMap, if the length of value is < 2, return Observable.of([]), otherwise return what you are already returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to reactive search if the value length > 2 do api search else clear data.

If I understood right by clearing you mean pushing empty array down to stream:

```
this.userList = this.userNameCtrl.valueChanges
    .debounceTime(400)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .switchMap(value => {
        if(value.length > 2) {
            return this._userService.searchUsers(value);
        } else {
            return Observable.of([]);
        }
    });
```

> The other question is why Rxjs do operator not work in angular 2?
>
> ```
> this.userList = this.userNameCtrl.valueChanges.do(d => console.log(d));
> ```

This code doesn't output anything because you need to subscribe to observable first

```
this.userList = this.userNameCtrl.valueChanges
    .do(d => console.log(d))
    subscribe(() => {});

// or simply

this.userList = this.userNameCtrl.valueChanges
    subscribe(d => console.log(d));
```

Comment: hi Sergev
thanks a lot. It works now.
I thought do as subscribe operator, I am wrong.